# Check if data set has value before updating

Tags: angular

I have the following problem with trying to update a data set.

This is the default data set

```
{
  "defaultOptionId": null,
  "hasClarity": null,
  "hasSinglePortfolio": true,
  "isComprehensive": null,
  "isLifestage": null,
  "lifestage": null,
  "portfolioOptionId": null,
  "defaultLabelName": "Single portfolio – Real Return Focus"
}
```

Now am I am trying to assign a value to it

```
this.benefit.investmentStrategy.defaultLabelName = this.defaultInvestmentStrategyArray.find(x => x.value == changes).label;
```

I get the following error at the moment

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'label' of undefined
```

Comment: Of course you are returning a null object from your find() function, please copy paste here find output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `this.defaultInvestmentStrategyArray.find(x => x.value == changes)` returns `undefined`, it means it can't find anything based on that predicate. You need to handle the case where it's `undefined`:

```js
const found = this.defaultInvestmentStrategyArray.find(x => x.value == changes);
this.benefit.investmentStrategy.defaultLabelName = 
    found != undefined ? found.label : "Default Label";
```

Comment: This code does not work, because the return value is not `null` if the `find` function does not find any values. Have a look at the `find` [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

Comment: @ngfelixl The return value is `undefined` if the `find` function does not find anything. When using double equals (`==` or `!=`) `null` and `undefined` behave the same way, so the above code will work as expected. Take a look at this: https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/

Comment: @IraklisGkougkousis Thanks, this work in the context of this problem

Comment: You are right! Thanks for clarification! Haven't had the two-equals in mind. Sorry for exclamation!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that it does not find any item in your `find` function. So it returns an `undefined` and `undefined` does not have a property `label`. The problem is not adding a property. You can check if the value exist, and if it does not exist (is undefined) you can either skip this step or define a default label or whatever you want.

```js
const elementContainingChanges = this.defaultInvestmentStrategyArray.find(x => x.value == changes);

if (elementContainingChanges) {
  this.benefit.investmentStrategy.defaultLabelName = elementContainingChanges.label;
}
```